# how to replace the last + with =?

Tags: string, output

```
total = 0
number = 1
until = int(input("Until: "))

while total < until:
    print(number, end = " + ")
    total += number
    number += 1

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a condition to check whether you have reached the end of loop and then print '=' in that case. Something like this.

```
total = 0

number = 1

until = int(input("Until: "))

while total < until:
    total += number

    if total >= until:
        print(number, end=" = ")
    else:
        print(number, end = " + ")

    number += 1
print(total)
```